# Best way to save data in iPod Touch/iPhone Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, persistence, ipod

I am writing a very simple application, for the iPhone. Unfortunately I am really a newbie.
What I am trying to do is to save data at the end of a user experience. This data is really simple, only string or int, or some array.

Later I want to be able to retrieve that data, therefore I also need an event ID (I suppose).

Could you please point out the best way, API or technology to achieve that, XML, plain text, serialization... ?

Comment: If it's a single integer or string, a plain text file should be sufficient. Look in the iPhone API for File I/O, or possibly Data Serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is a good choice for small amounts of data.

If you need to manage something larger than a kilobyte or so, you might consider using the `initWithContentsOfFile:` methods of `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` to read in a .plist file. To write the file, use the `writeToFile:atomically:` methods. This file needs to go in your app's documents directory.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Straight forward and easy to use. This will handle all File I/O for you, and takes only a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Me and my team created a simple class for this purpose which as Mark pointed out makes use of `NSUserDefaults`.  Hopefully this helps you out...

http://getsetgames.com/2009/10/07/saving-and-loading-user-data-and-preferences/